# How do you label a beeswarm plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to a beeswarm plot I am making using ggplot2. However, it seems as if the labels are pointing to the center line, and not the individual dots. Here is my code:

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(tidyverse)

DataTest <- tibble(Category = c(LETTERS),
                   Year = runif(26, 2016, 2016),
                   Size = runif(26, min = 5, max = 10),
                   SalesGrowth = runif(26, -1, 1))

ggplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_quasirandom(DataTest,
                   mapping = aes(factor(Year), 
                                 SalesGrowth,
                                 size = Size)) +
  geom_label_repel(DataTest %>% filter(Category %in% c('A', 'B', 'C')),
                   mapping = aes(factor(Year), 
                                 SalesGrowth,
                                 label = Category),
                   box.padding = 2) +
  scale_size_binned() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

And here is what the output is looking like visually. I want my labels to point to the respective dots.

[image: sample ggplot output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Make use of `position_quasirandom` in `geom_label_repel`
2. As a general rule when using `ggrepel`, pass the whole data to `geom_label_repel` and set undesired labels equal to `""` instead of filtering the data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggrepel)

DataTest <- data.frame(Category = c(LETTERS),
                   Year = runif(26, 2016, 2016),
                   Size = runif(26, min = 5, max = 10),
                   SalesGrowth = runif(26, -1, 1))

set.seed(42)

ggplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_quasirandom(DataTest,
                   mapping = aes(factor(Year), 
                                 SalesGrowth,
                                 size = Size)) +
  geom_label_repel(data = DataTest, mapping = aes(factor(Year), 
                                 SalesGrowth,
                                 label = ifelse(Category %in% c('A', 'B', 'C'), Category, "")),
                   position=position_quasirandom(),
                   box.padding = 2, seed = 42) +
  scale_size_binned() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]