# How to position labels correctly in a grouped beeswarm plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, ggbeeswarm

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_quasirandom(pch = 15, size= 6, alpha=0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gear), 
            position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), 
            vjust = -0.5, 
            size = 3)
```

This code generates the following plot:

[image]

My question is: How can I accurately position the numbers within the squares on this plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this is vanilla ggplot by setting a seed in `position_jitter`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 6, alpha = 0.7,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gear), 
            position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31), 
            size = 3, color = "black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I found the answer [How do you label a beeswarm plot in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069124/how-do-you-label-a-beeswarm-plot-in-ggplot2). There is a `position_quasirandom()` function in `ggbeeswarm` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_quasirandom(pch = 15, size= 6, alpha=0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gear), 
            position = position_quasirandom(), 
            vjust = 0.5, 
            size = 3,
            color = "black")
```

[image]